# Visualizing A Directory's File Structure and File Contents

Tags: file, graphics

I am interested in creating a tool that can be run from the command line (pref. linux) and which will scour a select group of files (think .gitignore in reverse), parse those files, and create an image that looks like this [Conceptboard](https://app.conceptboard.com/board/sukg-nipx-ixqn-y6h2-sa7a#). It doesn't need to look exactly like that, but I should be able to control graphical effects and layout of the boxed elements. Each boxed element should simply have the file name up top, and the contents of the file below.

My questions are:

- What tools are available for this type of project?
- Where would I logically start?
- How long should I expect this to take me?

edit: graphviz could definitely work, but is it able to show file contents?

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz can't directly show file contents, but I've often coupled it with code in java or python to build the appropriate .dot file, then run graphviz on that .dot file to produce the final graphic, something like this pseudocode:

```
open .dot text file and add graphviz header information
for each file in directory:
   save filename for future reference
   read and save file contents

   create node in .dot file formatted with filename at top and contents below

for each file in directory:
   parse file to locate links to other files
   if filename has been processed above, add a link line to .dot output file
add graphviz footer to .dot file
run DOT on .dot file
```

the final .dot file would look something like this, only much longer:

```
digraph fileStructure {
    node [shape=box, color=black, fontsize=14, fillcolor=white, style=filled]
    1  [label="filename\nfile contents"]
    2  [label="filename\nfile contents"]
    3  [label="filename\nfile contents"]

    1 -> 2 
    1 -> 3 
}
```

There are libraries for most major programming language to simplify the process of creating .dot files and running graphviz, but it's not too hard to do directly.

How long it would take depends on your skill level, but I wouldn't think this would take more than a few hours to complete.